# Opencart custom smart filters

Tags: seo, opencart, opencart-module

I have an **Opencart 3.0.3.2** installation with the Complete SEO Package installed.

I want to **implement custom logic for filter urls** in the category pages. I want to make the urls **SEF (SEO friendly)**.

Now when I filter by manufacturer the urls becomes something like:

```
/my-category?fm=32
```

I want it to look like

```
/my-category/iphone-12
```

I tried adding a rule to the complete SEO plugin but it works only for urls which are not yet mapped (it needs the raw route= part). My category listing page is already handled by the complete SEO package and it doesn't accept a second edit to the url logic.

Is there a way I can programatically map an SEO url like /my-category?fm=32 to a custom url ?

I need this to happen programatically since I have a lot of manufacturers and don't want to add them manually, but fetch them from the database and create the mapping in the code instead.

The store uses the Journal theme and I think the handling for the ?fm part comes from there.

I've tried editting both seo_url.php file and registering my own, but gost lost in the code and I don't think they actually did something. I am not posting code because I don't think it's relevant since it is very very far from doing something.

If someone ever implemented SEF filters for opencart I would be very thankful for guidance.